# Why do I get the error "TypeError: list object is not callable"?

Tags: python, list

I want the print the item on the middle index of the list:

```
lst=['a','b','v','c','d',]
middle=(len(lst)-1)/2
middle1=int(middle)
print(middle)
print(lst(middle1))
```

When I compiled the code I got the following error:

```
 print(lst(middle))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, square brackets [] should be used when accessing an element at a specific index in a list. You are currently using parentheses (), which is leading to an error. Instead, the correct syntax would be:

```
print(lst[middle1])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'v', 'c', 'd', ]

middle = (len(lst) - 1) / 2

middle1 = int(middle)

print(lst[middle1])
```